# Как менять содержимое TextView в header_menu у Navigation Drawer в Android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

Как менять содержимое TextView в header_menu у Navigation Drawer в Android studio?
При создании Navigation Drawer в Android studio создаются куча классов, и не понятно как мне поменять text у TextView который находится в header_menu из базы данных. Допустим если я хочу указать в хэдере логин и пароль пользователя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нашел, нужно такое прописать:

```
View navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView login = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.logintx);
```